# How to fill the group SWT widget with necessary details inside the border

Tags: java, eclipse, swt

I'm having a tree View and I'm having a group named 'Details' which displays the details of the selected item (when selected) in the tree view.

I'm unable to set the string inside the group border, when using the SWT Groups.
I'm able to only set the Title using the "group.setText()" method which sets the title for the group.

```
    --Details-----------------
   |                          |
   |  item 1 is selected      |
   |                          |
    --------------------------
```

I want to display the selection as shown in the above Figure.

Comment: Any method exists for setting this data ? I searched all the methods of this class and I'm unable to set the data inside the border with any of the Group method(s).

Comment: @greg-449: Hi Greg, any idea on how to set the data inside the SWT widget Group ?

Comment: You can't use @xxx to send messages to people who have not commented on a question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Group` is just a `Composite` with a title, if you want things inside it you must add additional controls as children.

Something like:

```
final Group group = new Group(parent, SWT.NONE);
group.setText("Details");

group.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, false));

Label label1 = new Label(group, SWT.NONE);
label1.setText("Label 1");

Text text1 = new Text(group, SWT.LEAD | SWT.BORDER);
text1.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.CENTER, true, false));

Label label2 = new Label(group, SWT.NONE);
label2.setText("Label 2");

Text text2 = new Text(group, SWT.LEAD | SWT.BORDER);
text2.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.CENTER, true, false));
```